# Pig Latin group by array_elem

Tags: apache-pig

I've got an `array_elem:int` field that I would like to include in the group function, but it gives me error

```
Sorry, group by complex types will be supported soon
```

Wondering if there is a way to convert this array_elem into a string.

```
ex: [1,2,3] to "[1,2,3]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just find out the UDF to do the job. Array_elem is technically a bag, so use the BagToString UDF to convert it to a string, then you should be able to group by using that string.

```
DEFINE BAGTOSTRING org.apache.pig.builtin.BagToString();

...

B = FOREACH A GENERATE BAGTOSTRING(array_field) as string_field;
grouped_B = GROUP B BY string_field;
```